# Twitter Boostrap 3 grid margin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created following scaffold:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    first column
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    second column
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    third column
  </div>
</div>
```

Every column has background with 1px border. I would like to add `margin-right: 15px` to every column bot if applied, third column goes lower to the second `row`.

How can I set 15px space between columns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of modifying the bootstrap CSS directly (which may cause you problems later on updating to subsequent versions) I would recommend you place your own custom container within your columns (say with the class .foo) with a css statement specifying how you want it to display. For example

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="foo">
         first column
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="foo">
         second column
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="foo">
         third column
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

with the CSS;

```
.foo:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right:15px;
}
```

Example : http://cdpn.io/eDBCJ